# How to enable SSO on mobile using Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, single-sign-on

I need to launch another mobile app on the same mobile device from Salesforce1. I have implemented that functionality.It is currently just launching the other app by invoking the app specific URI. Now I need to enable SSO on mobile such that logged in Salesforce1 user can seamlessly login to the other app as well without having him to type username and password again.Could anyone share any ideas how to achieve that

Comment: What functionality that other app does .How does it handle its own session ?There are lot of questions that arise here .What have you tried or browsed online ?

Comment: The other app is a native iOS app for business users to access the data in other systems. I wanted to try SAML or OAuth but as these apps require URL and it is a mobile app that doesn't have URL(only a URI),I couldn't. iOS App captures username and password of the user,saves it and validates it against an authentication system and gets the token to be passed for subsequent requests.Token will expire in an hour. When user launches the app after an hour, saved user credentials will be used to login.

Comment: There are other native iOS Apps that are available.They all share same keychain so that user logged into one app can be automatically logged into the other app as well. Not sure if Salesforce1 allows us to store keychain so that Salesforce1 also can be one of them.

Comment: This is definitely great question .Let me see if i get hold of someone from SFDC who can help us here

Comment: @Suneel Any updates on this?

Comment: Any update on this?